# Group by ranges in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, group-by, range

I have a SQLite table which contains a numeric field `field_name`. I need to group by ranges of this column, something like this: `SELECT CAST(field_name/100 AS INT), COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY CAST(field_name/100 AS INT)`, but including ranges which have no value (COUNT for them should be `0`). And I can't get how to perform such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a join and (though kludgy) an extra table.

The extra table would contain each of the values you want a row for in the response to your query (this would not only fill in missing  `CAST(field_name/100 AS INT)` values between your returned values, but also let you expand it such that if your current groups were 5, 6, 7 you could include 0 through 10.

In other flavors of SQL you'd be able to right join or full outer join, and you'd be on your way.  Alas, [SQLite doesn't offer these](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html).

Accordingly, we'll use a cross join (join everything to everything) and then filter.  If you've got a relatively small database or a small number of groups, you're in good shape.  If you have large numbers of both, this will be a very intensive way to go about this (the cross join result will have #ofRowsOfData * #ofGroups rows, so watch out).

Example:

TABLE: groups_for_report

```
desired_group
-------------
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Table: data

```
fieldname    other_field
---------    -----------
250          somestuff
230          someotherstuff
600          stuff
```

you would use a query like

```
select groups_for_report.desired_group, count(data.fieldname)
from data
cross join groups_for_report
where CAST(fieldname/100.0 AS INT)=desired_group
group by desired_group;
```

Comment: And what if I have several million of rows in the table and thousands of groups?

Comment: Then you have to create those thousands of groups. (It might be easier to detect 'missing' groups in the code that reads the SQL result.)

Comment: Interestingly, I just learned that postgres supports an iteration method... not that helpful if you're limited to SQLite but worth considering if you move to a more robust backend.